# How to show an existing form in a project

Tags: vb.net

Newbie alert!

I'm trying to show another form when a user successfully inputs the correct username and password. Like a login screen

But on button click event, the code below is highlighted

```
Form2.Show()
```

The second form won't show and the code above has wiggly lines below it

This error shows: Property access must assign to the property or use its value

What can be the problem?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Share relevant piece of code so others can take a look

Comment: I hope this is clearer. The code is "Form2.Show" and its in a button

Comment: Did you create the instance of the form?  Dim _form as Form2 = new Form2().

Comment: I tried it. But its still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of your form.

On button click event,

```
Dim frm2 As New Form2()
frm2.Show()
```

Comment: Why? I have just been using Form2.Show()

Answer (score 0):

Do not use shared (static) method to display form. Use instance method instead.
Code below will display Form2 modally and after that, disposes it.

```
Using f2 As New Form2
  f2.ShowDialog(Me)
End Using
```

Comment: Tried it but error shows "Cannot access a disposed object"

Comment: Code example above works for showing Form2 modally once. Of course you can not use instance members after form was disposed (outside of Using block). First learn basics about OOP and how to use instances of classes. Unfortunately VB.NET allows you to use everything statically by default, which is horrific way for beginners.

Comment: Update! I replaced "Me" with Form2. I think there's something weird but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose you don't want it modal?

Comment: When using Me keyword, it depends on from where it is called. I am supposing that you are calling it from instance of main form. If you dont want it modal, then you can not use Using...End Using.